# how to achieve join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

folks, can anyone tell me how I can achieve below query in join which has more performance as compared to below query

```
SELECT *, count(*) c FROM question_ans_word where answer_id in
  (select answer_id from question_ans_word where keywords_id in
     (SELECT id FROM uniqueword where word like "minimum")
  )
group by answer_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is how you'd do this using joins. Whether or not it will perform better is something I can't say anything about:

```
select a.*, count(*) c
  from question_ans_word a
  inner join question_ans_word qw
    on qw.answer_id = a.answer_id
  inner join uniqueword u
    on u.id = qw.keywords_id
  where u.word like "minimum"
  group by a.answer_id
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this from my understanding...

```
From question_ans_word qaw
JOIN uniqueword uw on qaw.keywords_id = uw.id and word like "minimum"
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm SQL Server... `INNER JOIN` is defaulted when just the `JOIN` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select *, count(*) c from question_ans_word qw INNER JOIN uniqueword uw ON uw.id = qw.keywords_id WHERE uw.word like "minimum" group by answer_id
```

Comment: Please tell me, why you need count?

Comment: i want count for ordering